# Secure way of storing user's credential in a session

Tags: session, credentials

I am aware that you might be thinking "*Do not store user's credentials, hash them with salt+pepper you idiot!*", but please read on.

I'm working on a project that is going to ask the user about the credentials (login/password) for its database. Those credentials will be tried against the database, and if the connexion is successful, I will "keep" them for doing some work on the database as asked by the user (create a table, change a row, do a SELECT, etc).

That means, every time the user will do something, I will reconnect to the database before doing his request => I can't hash the credentials because they will be useless for the subsequent requests. It's like phpMyAdmin, if you like.

So I came up with various possibilities, but each of them has flaws. I'm looking for suggestions to determine which one would be better.

1. **Just use a Session cookie with login/password in clear**. But allow only the use over HTTPS : This on is the most simple way to implement. The only drawback I see is if there is a XSS on the client side, the credentials can be retrieved.
2. **The same session cookie, but with encrypted login/password using AES**. It's what it is used by PhpMyAdmin I believe. I can go further by only allowing HTTPS too.
3. **Store the credential in clear in a local session storage** (session.db in sqlite), and use a Token for the client that will be retrieve using the given token + browser details. Drawback : If an attacker access the session.db file, he will be able to read the sessions that haven't been removed  from the file. I don't think encrypting them will be useful, since if he can access the session.db, he can certainly also access the SECRET_KEY used to encrypt them.

What do you think? What would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend against using 1. or 2., for the following reasons:

- The credentials are useless for the client
- Sending he credentials over the wire on every request (in whaever form) is not a good idea

So what stays, is a variation on Version 3., store it in the session. This has one important property: **If your session storage is not secure, this means, your server is not secure. Game over.**

To protect against an attack on session.db nonetheless, you could have a hardcoded key base in your app. This key base is salted with the session token and then hashed, the result is used as a key to en- and decrypt the client credentials. This way, an attacker would need to compromise the session.db AND your app (to get the key base). If he is able to do that, nothing will help you.

Comment: Ah nice, that would mean the key base is the pepper, the token the salt. Moreover, this means if the attacker access the session.db AND the key base, he also will need the token to decrypt the credentials : IMPOSSIBRU :D

Comment: Sorry, not impossible: The Token must be in the session.db to look up the corresponding record! Even if you also spice it with a key base, if the attacker gets the key base, it's game over. **If the attacker can hack your app, he can typically get all data, that your app can see**. That's sad, but still the truth.

Comment: yeah you're right. But still, it's better than sending credentials for every request. I'm gonna go with this! Thanks :)

Comment: Wouldn't just using another cookie with the token helped instead of using session token? Then it would not be possible to retrieve the creds as token would not be stored in session.db.

Comment: @EugenRieck "If the attacker can hack your app, he can typically get all data, that your app can see" We're assuming this app is like a react-app. What if the key base is saved on  the server-side app e.g Java? That way the hacker would not have access to the key, isn't it?

Comment: If the hacker has the encrypted key and the plain text (he knows his own password). Is it possible by rainbow tabe/brute force that he finds out the salt(or pepper whatever)?

Comment: @veritas if the key is saved on the server, then the client needs a way to access it - this opens another box of pandora.

Comment: @veritas if a hacker has the resources to brute-force a modern key, then nothing can help you